# Rendering different elements based on promise's result

Tags: reactjs, promise

I'm trying to make a login/logout button based on my user authentication status. since I'm fetching this data from my api, I cant seem to return the data itself, only the promise and since in reactjs the .then() function cant be used I don't know how to access the data I need.

this is the function that fetches the data from api, I want it to return "data.success" which is a boolean, but instead a promise is returned.

```
let checkAuth = () => {
    return fetch('/v1/checkLogin')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { 
        return data.success
    })    
}
```

react code calling above function :

```
{
    (checkAuth())
    ? <button>logout</button>
    : <button>login</button>
}
```

any help is appreciated =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature of requests, the outer code will have already returned before the promise is resolved. That is why it returns a promise instead of your data.

A better approach to get through this is to use "useState" "useEffect" hooks

- use "useEffect" to fetch the data when the component renders for the first time
- use "useState" store the fetched data to a variable and use it in ways you want

```
export default LoginComponent = () => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false); // False initially

  let checkAuth = () => {
    const result = await fetch("/v1/checkLogin") // Wait for promise to resolve
    const data = result.json();
    setAuthenticated(data.success); // Set Data. (You can set just "data" if you want the whole data object)
  };

  // useEffect which fires once when the component initially renders
  useEffect(() => {
   checkAuth()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
     {authenticated ? <button>logout</button> : <button>login</button
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a state with `useEffect` to update the UI accordingly

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isAccess, setIsAccess] = useState(); // initialize your state

  let checkAuth = () => {
    return fetch("/v1/checkLogin")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setIsAccess(data.success); //set the value for your state
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth()
  }, [])

  //after the state update, your UI will be re-rendered with the latest value which you expected
  return (
    <div>{isAccess ? <button>logout</button> : <button>login</button>}</div>
  );
};
```